# Como unir dos paginas html sin usar iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

La idea es que si tengo dos páginas en HTML las pueda unir, y pueda llamar a sus métodos y al DOM entre ambas páginas, sin utilizar un controlador como `PHP`

Ejemplo:

**pagina1.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
    <script>
       function FuncionPagina1(){
          return "mundo";
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="mundo" class="mundoClass">MUNDO!!!</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```

**pagina2.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Ejemplo</title>
    <script>
       function FuncionPagina1(){
          return "hola";
       }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="hola" class="holaClass">Hola</h1>    
</body>
</html>
```

¿Cómo puedo unir **pagina1** y **pagina2**, y poder llamar con acceso simple a ellas como si se tratase de estar en la misma página¿ Con esto me refiero a que si estoy parado en la **pagina1**, pueda llamar al `id="mundo"` o `class="mundoClass"` y viceversa, que de **pagina2** pueda llamar a sus propios `id` y `class`, y si fuera posible incluso a sus funciones de JavaScript.

**Nota**: Cabe señalar que la idea es que sea sin `iframe`

Comment: ¿Las dos páginas abiertas al mismo tiempo? ¿Sólo una? ¿Puede una abrir la otra en una nueva pestaña/ventana?

Comment: Nono. En php por ejemplo puedes colocar include() y es como si pagina1 añadiera a pagina2 y pudiera llamar a todos sus metodos y variables. Consultaba algo así en html. Agradezco tu interés!

Comment: Creo que se hizo una pregunta muy parecida hace unos días y tenía varias respuestas. No sé si la has visto, voy a ver si la encuentro y te pongo un enlace.

Comment: la generé yo mismo, pero por mi mala explicación la cerraron. Así que preferí eliminarla y redactarla mejor

Comment: Bueno, me ahorro buscarla entonces :). Pensaba que tenía un par de respuestas buenas para lo que pides

Comment: Agradezco tu interés @AlvaroMontoro :D

Comment: José: Es muy bueno que hagas el esfuerzo por mejorar tus preguntas. Cuando te cierran una pregunta, es posible reabrirla. En muchos casos lo mejor es hacer el intento por queda el historial del esfuerzo que has realizado. En el caso de esta pregunta y otras tantas falta que el OP mencione lo que ha buscado/intentado. De todas formas te dejé una respuesta. Nota: Las preguntas que se eliminan quedan disponibles a usuarios que tienen cierto nivel de reputación.

Comment: Gracias @Rubén por tu comentario. Habian votado para reapertura pero no alcanzo para ello y la cerraron finalmente. Por ello preferí eliminar por que es algo que me gustaría saber como hacer. Ademas ayudaría a que fuera mucho mas simple y dinámico una pagina :D

Comment: En el caso de esta pregunta, como te mencionaba, falta que menciones lo buscado/investigado, al menos, menciones cómo hicistes tus búsquedas y porque lo encontrado no te sirvió.

Comment: Esencialmente busque como hacer, y me tope con `iframe` pero no me parecio lo mas adecuado. Y terminé solucionando que **pagina1** mediante `ajax` fuera a buscar un archivo `php`, donde solo hacia un `include()` a la **pagina2** y como respuesta me mandaba todo el html, por lo que este lo cargaba posterior en un `div`, y funciono como crei. Pero eso me dio a pensar si se podía hacer sin tener que pasar por un controlador

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Es perfectamente posible utilizando [`load` de jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/load/), solo debes tener cuidado de no incluir la página 1 **dentro** de la página 2 que a su vez contenga la página 1, sería un ciclo infinito y la verdad no sé cómo se comporte. En fin, regresando al tema:

```
<div id="pagina2"></div>

<script>
    $("#pagina2").load("/pagina2.html");
</script>
```

Incluso puedes ser más específico y definir qué sección de la página quieres cargar:

```
<script>
    $("#pagina2").load("/pagina2.html body");
</script>
```

y definir alguna acción para cuando la carga del documento termine:

```
<script>
    $("#pagina2").load("/pagina2.html form", function(){
        $("#inputDePagina2").focus();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Y en caso de que pagina1 quisiera acceder al DOOM posteriormente al load? y puedo acceder a las funciones de javascript de la pagina2? Agradezco tu respuesta!

Comment: Precisamente en el último ejemplo te dejo el cómo puedes ejecutar acciones después del `load` y si incluyes por ejemplo el body y dentro de éste tienes los scripts de la **página 2**, no vas a tener problemas para invocarlos. Revisa la página de referencia que te dejé :D

Comment: Voy a revisar y te comento :D

Comment: Tanto Kroneaux Schneider como @Alvaro Montoro tienen una respuesta correcta. Sin embargo por tema de compatibilidad con los navegadores, jquery seria una respuesta que abarca mejor. Agradezco sus respuestas! +1 a ambos ;)

Answer (score 7):

En HTML puedes utilizar `link` e importar archivos. Seguramente ya lo usas con archivos de CSS para añadir estilos a tu página, pero lo puedes usar también para importar otras páginas HTML.

Este método te va a permitir usar las funciones JS de la otra página directamente (los `script` se ejecutan en el momento del `import`), y para acceder a las variables de la página importada vas a necesitar un par de líneas (mover la página importada a una variable, buscar los elementos en esa variable en lugar de en el propio DOM). Nada complicado.

Entonces, para importar una página en otra, sólo tendrías que hacer esto:

```
<link rel="import" href="./pagina-importada.html" />
```

Si la página importada tiene funciones JS, las puedes llamar directamente, y para leer las variables sería algo como esto:

```
// importar página a una variable
var contenido = document.querySelector("selector-para-tag-link-import").import;
// seleccionar el elemento en la página importada
var el = contenido.querySelector("selector-del-elemento-deseado-en-pagina-importada");
```

Una cosa importante a tener en cuenta: los `import` pueden no estar soportados por todos los navegadores, y se rigen por las reglas CORS, es decir, deben tener el mismo origen o permitir que la página sea importada por página de otros orígenes.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo:

### pagina1.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Página 1</title>
        <script>
        function miFuncion() {
            console.log(1);
        }
        function leeAux() {
            // cargamos el contenido de la página importada en una variable
            var contenido = document.getElementById("pagina-secundaria").import;
            // buscamos el elemento que queramos
            var el = contenido.querySelector("#aux");
            // ya podemos operar con el elemento con normalidad
            console.log(el.innerHTML);
        }
        </script>
        <link rel="import" href="./page2.html" id="pagina-secundaria" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Página 1
        <script>
        // llamada a una función propia
        miFuncion();
        // llamada a una función de la página importada
        miFuncion2();
        // llamada a una función propia que lee elementos de la página importada
        leeAux();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

### pagina2.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Página 2</title>
        <script>
        function miFuncion2() {
            console.log(2);
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="aux">
            Página 2
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Revisaré y te comento :D

Comment: Tanto @Kroneaux Schneider como Alvaro Montoro tienen una respuesta correcta. Sin embargo por tema de compatibilidad con los navegadores, jquery seria una respuesta que abarca mejor. Agradezco sus respuestas! +1 a ambos ;)

Answer (score 1):

No se debe tomar todo el texto y adjuntarlo porque hay etiquetas que deben usarse una única vez por página, en su lugar, toma el contenido por partes.

Lo primero es usar [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) en la página en la que quieres jalar los recursos externos, en este caso una página HTML.

> El método fetch() toma un argumento obligatorio, la ruta de acceso al recurso que desea recuperar. Devuelve una [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Promise) que resuelve en [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Response) a esa petición, sea o no correcta. También puede pasar opcionalmente un objeto de opciones init como segundo argumento (ver [Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Request)).

Aunque lo anterior es posible, no lo considero una "buena práctica universal". En cuanto a las funciones, en ciertos casos lo mejor que ponerlas en un archivo, es decir crear una librería, y cargar este en cada página que se requieran las funciones que contiene.

En cuanto a las etiquetas HTML en ciertos casos lo ideal es poner la estructura en una página y mediante clases y/o JavaScript manejar la lógica de, es decir controlar, cuándo se deben mostrar.

**Bibliografía**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript
- https://jquery.com/

Comment: La verdad es que entiendo lo que mencionas. Pero que de pagina1 puedas obtener los tag de pagina2, es la consulta que hago. Se tambien que es mejor ponerlo en un archivo, sin embargo hay veces que creo pequeñas funciones que la dejo en la pagina por otros motivos de dinamizar las paginas

Comment: Agregué el enlace a Fetch API