# Herencia entre paginas html

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo una página web donde solo tengo el index, ya listo, con HTML5, CSS y JavaScript. Quiero crear más páginas pero quisiera heredar del index algunas cosas, como el encabezado, menú y footer. Cómo pudiera hacerlo? con java script puedo manipular el DOM de las nuevas páginas y heredar esto e la primera?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Como incluir HTML en otro HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70206/como-incluir-html-en-otro-html)

Comment: Bienvenido al mundo de las plantillas.

Comment: Puedes empezar revisando la doc de algún motor de plantillas, como twig (por ej).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te adjunto una alternativa usando javascript puro, saludos

index.html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>How to load templates</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div><h3>Container</h3></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
    <script>
      function load_templates() {
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML =
          "<object data='header.html'>";
        document.getElementById("footer").innerHTML =
          "<object data='footer.html'>";
      }
      load_templates();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

header.html

```
<header>Este es el header</header>
```

footer.html

```
<footer>Este es el footer</footer>
```

Comment: gracias, probé el ejemplo y funciona. El problema que me presenta ahora es de estilo. En la página header hice el menú sin problemas y le puse los css y bien. Pero al llamarlo dentro de index me aparece todo dentro de un pequeño cuadro. Actualizaré con fotos ela pregunta para que sea más fácil de entender.

Answer (score 1):

Para esto te recomiendo investigar acerca de los **Web Components** ya que te va ayudar y facilitar más el flujo de desarrollo y realizando las mejores prácticas para desarrollo web.

Realmente tienes varias opciones para solucionar tu requisito, yo te presento dos opciones:

1.- **Hacerlo con PHP**, puedes crear un archivo PHP con tu Maquetación de HTML y luego sólo quedaría llamarlo desde donde lo ocupes, por ejemplo, creas un archivo llamado **footer.php** y ahí agregas tu HTML y después lo llamarías desde index.php o desde cualquier otro archivo PHP.

2.- **Utilizar un framework de JS**, para eso hay múltiples opciones como Gatsby, React, Vue JS, estos frameworks están diseñados para trabajar con web components.

Comment: Tienes razón, Node JS no es un framework, y te agradezco mucho tu recomendación, la tomaré mucho en cuenta para poder mejorar mis aportes.

Comment: Un ejemplo concreto le ayudaría mucho