# ¿Se puede cargar de forma dinamica HTML5?

Tags: html5

Buenas Tardes

Estoy preparando una web que tiene un footer muy elaborado, por lo he pensado en la idea de preparar un html con solo el footer y que el resto de las páginas lo cargaran de forma dinámica, así allí donde quiera poner el footer se pondría y para modificarlo seria mas sencillo.

¿Existe alguna forma de hacer esto con HTML5?

Comment: Existen ya varias preguntas sobre este tema en este sitio. Voy a buscar y poner enlaces, pero te recomiendo que busques también por aquí porque la pregunta era muy parecida si recuerdo bien.

Comment: Además, no especificas el lenguaje con el que trabajas

Comment: Mira estas preguntas, creo que se parecen bastante a lo que buscas: [Como incluir HTML en otro HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/70206/250) o  [Como unir dos paginas html sin usar iframe](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/65890/250)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar el include de php.

```
 <?php include 'footer.html'; ?>
```

Los archivos son incluidos con base en la ruta de acceso dada
mas información -> [Include](http://php.net/manual/es/function.include.php)

Comment: nunca se ha especificado que OP utilice PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar algun Cliente, sería lo mas viable, ya sea:

- AngularJS
- JQuery

En donde puedes usarlas como plantillas, por ejemplo en mi caso, creé un login con una plantilla, donde en Angular cargo las plantillas.

**Plantilla HTML**

```
<html ng-app="appInicioSU">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/appInicioSU.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scriptLoginSU.js"></script>
        </head>    
        <body >
            <!--Clase contenedora que se encarga de cargar las plantillas de AngularJS-->
            <div class="container" col-md-4 col-md-offset-4>
              <ui-view></ui-view>
            </div>
          </body>
          <!--Pie de pagina de la interfaz del proyecto-->
          <footer>        
            <div class="">
              <center>
                <a class="mbr-footer__link text-gray" href="#/">Términos de Uso</a>  |
                <a class="mbr-footer__link text-gray" href="#/">Política de Privacidad</a>            
                <br>
                <p class="mbr-footer__copyright" style="color:white;">Versión 1.0.0-prueba.1</p>
                <br>
              </center>
             </div>
          </footer>
        </html>
```

**Vista Contenedora**

```
<form class="form-signin" id="formSU">
<h3 class="form-signin-heading" align="center"></h3>
<input type="text"     class="form-control" name="usuarioSU"    placeholder="Usuario" required/>
<input type="password" class="form-control" name="contrasenaSU" placeholder="Contraseña" required/>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="">
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox"> Recuérdame
        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalContrasena">¿Olvidaste tú contraseña?</a>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="submit" class="botonSU btn btn-lg btn-info btn-block" id="botonSU" value="Iniciar Sesión">
```

**Angular JS**

```
//Dar de alta a la appRegistroEventos NG-appRegistroEventos
var app = angular.module('appInicioSU', ['ui.router'])
//Establecer los componentes que alimentan la app, partes en que se cambian los archivos.
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider)
{
  $stateProvider
  .state('inicioSU',
  {
      url: "/inicioSU",
      templateUrl: "views/adminLoginSU.html"
  });

  //Declaracion de direccion diferente, para redireccionar a la vista por defecto
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/inicioSU');
});
```

Puedes seguir investigando al respecto, esta es una de las muchas tantas formas posibles de realizar esto, realmente, direccionar entre hojas `html` con `href` si es que así lo hacias.